# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method

Tags: php, php7

Ошибка

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Error::status() in Z:\OSPanel\domains\deer\controller\general\error.php:6 Stack trace: #0 Z:\OSPanel\domains\deer\controller\general.php(39): require() #1 Z:\OSPanel\domains\deer\class\template.class.php(76): require('Z:\\OSPanel\\doma...') #2 Z:\OSPanel\domains\deer\index.php(39): template->controller('general') #3 {main} thrown in Z:\OSPanel\domains\deer\controller\general\error.php on line 6
```

**general\error.php**

```
$err = new error();

$error = (!empty($_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'])) ? $err->status($_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']) : $err->status(200);
```

**\controller\general\error.php**

```
class error
    {

         function status($code) {
            if ($code == 200) return true;

            $codes = array(
                   400 => array('400', 'Плохой запрос', 'Запрос не может быть обработан из-за синтаксической ошибки.'),
                   403 => array('403', 'Запрещено', 'Сервер отказывает в выполнении вашего запроса.'),
                   404 => array('404', 'Страница не найдена', 'Запрашиваемая страница не найдена на сервере.'),
                   405 => array('405', 'Метод не допускается', 'Указанный в запросе метод не допускается для заданного ресурса.'),
                   408 => array('408', 'Время ожидания истекло', 'Ваш браузер не отправил информацию на сервер за отведенное время.'),
                   500 => array('500', 'Внутренняя ошибка сервера', 'Запрос не может быть обработан из-за внутренней ошибки сервера.'),
                   502 => array('502', 'Плохой шлюз', 'Сервер получил неправильный ответ при попытке передачи запроса.'),
                   504 => array('504', 'Истекло время ожидания шлюза', 'Вышестоящий сервер не ответил за установленное время.'),
            );

            $return = (!empty($codes[$code])) ? $codes[$code] : array('001', '000 Неизвестная ошибка', 'Произошла неизвестная ошибка.');

            return $return;
        }

    }
```

как исправить?

Answer (score 1):

добавьте модификатор доступа к методу

```
public function status($code) {...}
```

Comment: Аналогично... не помогло